# Separate .d dependencies directories for Makefile

Tags: makefile

I'm using GNU make, which I thought would make this easier.

I'm trying to build in either build/Debug or build/Release, depending on whether the target is 'debug' or 'release'.

Here's the relevant excerpt of my makefile:

```
# Project files
SRC_DIRS = ../source ..source/[...], etc.
SRCS := $(shell find $(SRC_DIRS) -maxdepth 1 -name *.cpp -or -name *.cxx -or -name *.c -or -name *.s)
SRCS := $(sort $(SRCS))
vpath %.cpp $(SRC_DIRS)
vpath %.cxx $(SRC_DIRS)
vpath %.c $(SRC_DIRS)

# Object files
OBJS := $(addsuffix .o, $(notdir $(basename $(SRCS))))

# Dependencies
DEPS := $(OBJS:.o=.d)

debug:   DEPS_DIR = build/Debug
release: DEPS_DIR = build/Release
DEPS := $(addprefix $(DEPS_DIR)/, $(DEPS))
include $(DEPS)
```

The problem is that I can't get `$(DEPS)` to evaluate properly. It seems like the `DEPS` `addprefix` is being evaluated before the target-specific `DEPS_DIR` assignments, so that it's resulting in "/filename.d", since it thinks `$DEPS_DIR` is blank. However, if I go down further and under the actual targets add a `echo "DEPS_DIR = $(DEPS_DIR)"`, it expands correctly.

There's probably something obvious I'm doing wrong. How can I point `include` at the `DEPS` list in *either* of build/Debug or build/Release, depending on target?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've missed the part of the documentation on target-specific variables where it specifies that they are in effect *only* when expanding the recipes for rules.

Make works by reading in the entire makefile all at once and building its internal graph of targets and prerequisites, and only *after* that is complete does it look to see which targets should be built based on the command line, etc.  That's why order of rule definition, etc. mostly doesn't matter: make is not "running" the makefile as it is read in, as if it were a script.  So there's no way for a target-specific variable to impact what files are included by the `include` statement.

There are a few ways to do what you want.  The simplest and most portable one is to use a recursive invocation of make, like this:

```
debug:
        $(MAKE) DEPS_DIR=build/Debug realtarget
release:
        $(MAKE) DEPS_DIR=build/Release realtarget
```

Alternatively the `MAKECMDGOALS` make variable contains whatever goals were specified on the command line, so you can check this in a make `ifeq` statement or similar and set `DEPS_DIR` that way.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, I went with `MAKECMDGOALS` — I'd forgotten about it until I went digging back to see how I'd done something sort-of-similar in a previous project.